# CSS max-height transition double animation bug in webkit

Tags: ios, webkit, css-transitions

See this JSFiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ocawwqd/21/

Stack Overflow is insisting I include the code that I'm linking to, so here is the JS and CSS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show', function () {
    $('.reveal')[0].style.removeProperty('display');
    var height = $('.reveal')[0].scrollHeight;

    $('.reveal').css({ 'max-height': height, 'overflow':'hidden' });

    $('.reveal').removeClass('hide');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.reveal')[0].style.removeProperty('overflow');
        $('.reveal')[0].style.removeProperty('max-height');
    }, 501);
});

$(document).on('click', '.hide', function () {
    var height = $('.reveal')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('.reveal').css({'max-height': height, 'overflow':'hidden' });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.reveal').addClass('hide');
    }, 5);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.reveal').css('display', 'none');
    }, 505);
});
```

CSS

```
 a {
        color:blue;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .reveal {
        width:250px;
        background-color:#ccc;
        padding:10px;
        transition: all .5s;
        overflow:hidden;
        translate3d(0,.01%,0);
    }
    .reveal.hide {
        max-height:0 !important;
        padding-top:0;
        padding-bottom:0;
    }
```

The Basic Problem: 
I have a widget that I need to hide/show which has an unknown height. When hidden, the display must be set to 'none' to avoid tab index and form validation issues. So I'm using max-height property to make use of CSS transitions to animate the hiding and showing, and to swap the display from 'none' to 'block' (or just to the default by removing the display property from the element. The issue described happens in either case).

In my testing, I get a double animation only in OSX Safari, Chrome and Safari on iOS, and Android Stock mobile browser. (It works in Windows Chrome, FF, IE11, Android Chrome)

I've pinpointed when the double animation happens.
The first animation is correct, and happens when the max-height property is changed via JavaScript from 0 to whatever the content height is.

The second animation occurs when I then use a timer to remove the max-height property after the animation is complete.  I must remove the max height, because after visible, the element may get even more items added to it and so must be allowed to grow.

Has anyone encountered this or have a solution?

Comment: having this same problem now. You ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered a similar issue, but found that a lot of the *backface-visibility: hidden* suggestions haven't resolved it for iOS.

As you're already using JavaScript to set/unset the height properties, you can try to toggle an additional 'animating' class to the element before animating and after the animation's complete. If you do this prior to removing the height (or setting it back to 'auto'), iOS won't be trying to re-animate the height property that results in the flicker.

Taking your example http://jsfiddle.net/m2adrugn/2/:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show', function () {
    $('.reveal')[0].style.removeProperty('display');
    var height = $('.reveal')[0].scrollHeight;

    $('.reveal').css({ 'max-height': height, 'overflow':'hidden' });

    $('.reveal').addClass('animating').removeClass('hide');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.reveal').removeClass('animating');
        $('.reveal')[0].style.removeProperty('overflow');
        $('.reveal')[0].style.removeProperty('max-height');
    }, 501);
});

$(document).on('click', '.hide', function () {
    var height = $('.reveal')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('.reveal').addClass('animating').css({'max-height': height, 'overflow':'hidden' });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.reveal').addClass('hide');
    }, 5);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.reveal').css('display', 'none').removeClass('animating');
    }, 505);
});
```

CSS

```
    a {
        color:blue;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .reveal {
        width:250px;
        background-color:#ccc;
        padding:10px;
        overflow:hidden;
        translate3d(0,.01%,0);
    }
    .reveal.animating {
        transition: all .5s;        
    }
    .reveal.hide {
        max-height:0 !important;
        padding-top:0;
        padding-bottom:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change max-height to height. 
Worked for me.